# Runtime error after reportedly successful cx_Oracle install

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7-x64, cx-oracle

I installed `cx_Oracle` for `Python3.4` on `Windows 7 64-bit` using `easy_install` after both the binary and `pip` install attempts failed for various reasons.  Upon the install, I got a seemingly success confirmation:

```
Installed d:\homex\sftwr\python3.4\lib\site-packages\cx_oracle-5.1.3-py3.4-win32.egg
Processing dependencies for cx-Oracle
Finished processing dependencies for cx-Oracle
```

However, when I tried using it in my script (`import cx_Oracle`), I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_office_headcounts.py", line 5, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

What could be wrong?  I've been struggling to enable `Oracle` access from Python all day.

Comment: I have circumvented the problem (not to say solved it) by downgrading to Python 2.7, where cx_Oracle gets installed fine using easy_install

Comment: Are you using a 32bit or 64bit version of Python 3.4?

Comment: I downgraded to 2.7 and it all works fine